# Get elements which are not in second list

Tags: list, prolog, member

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get what 'Components' are not being used. So I created a list with all the 'Components' and 'In Use Components'.
My idea is to compare this lists and create another list with the elements that didn't match.

```
component('name 1', 1).
component('name 2', 2).
component('name 3', 3).
component('name 4', 4).
component('name 5', 5).

inUse(1, 'name 1').
inUse(1, 'name 3').
inUse(1, 'name 5').

comp_list(L):- findall(Comp, component(Comp, _), L).
inuse_list(L):- findall(Comp, inUse(_, Comp), L).
```

I don't know how to do something like this: `member('name comp', List).` where I can replace 'name comp' with every element of the other list.

Thanks in advance.

**Example:**

```
L1 = ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3', 'name 4', 'name 5'] %comp_list(L).
L2 = ['name 1', 'name 3', 'name 5']                     %inuse_list(L).

someRule(R):- comp_list(L1), inuse_list(L2),    %more code, to obtain a list R with:

R = ['name 2', 'name 4'] (Elements lacking on inuse_list)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of two lists and what you're trying to do since till now it's not clear at all...

Comment: Hello @coder . I've added the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a simple recursive predicate to obtain elements of `comp_list` that are not member of `inuse_list`:

```
obtain_elements([],_,[]).
obtain_elements([H|T],L,[H|T1]):-\+member(H,L),obtain_elements(T,L,T1).
obtain_elements([H|T],L,L2):-member(H,L),obtain_elements(T,L,L2).
```

and use it like:

```
someRule(R):- comp_list(L1),
              inuse_list(L2), 
              obtain_elements(L1,L2,R).
```

OR another way using `findall/3` predicate:

```
someRule(R):- comp_list(L1),
              inuse_list(L2), 
              findall(X,(member(X,L1),\+member(X,L2)),R).
```

Comment: I've used findall predicate and worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer is correct, it is much better to avoid lists as long as you can if you need to reason about facts and rules in the database.  In this case, a target unused components is easily defined as

`ununsed(Name) :-
    component(Name, _),
    \+ inUse(_, Name).`

This nicely enumerates the unused components.  If you want them in a list, use `findall/3` over `unused/1`.  In most cases though the definition of `unused/1` is way easier to combine with other pure logical relations.

In most cases *aggregation* primitives like `findall/3`, `aggregate/3`, etc., are best delayed until the very end or not used at all.